# Efficiently importing data into Mathematica

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, import

I have a graph data file `infile.txt`.

```
3 2 0 1 1 2
3 2 0 1 2 1
3 2 1 0 1 2
3 3 0 1 1 0 1 2
3 3 0 1 1 0 2 1
3 4 0 1 1 0 1 2 2 1
```

In this file, each row corresponds to a digraph in the following way:

- The first number is the number of vertices in this digraph;
- The second number is the number of arcs in this digraph;
- Remaining numbers represent arc in pairs.

For example, the last row in the given file corresponds to a digraph with 3 vertices and 4 arcs, and arcs are $(0,1)$,$(1,0)$,$(1,2)$,$(2,1)$.

I want to import it into *Mathematica* and construct a list of graphs accordingly. And my solution is:

```
mylist=Import["/path/to/infile.txt","Table"];
mylist=Drop[#,2]&/@mylist;
glist=Graph[DirectedEdge@@@Partition[#,2]]&/@mylist
```

My method is OK with small files.
However, it is extremely slow when the input file is large.
But I need to deal with large files a lot. 
So my questions are

1. <s>How to input such large files efficiently? `ReadList` seems to be good option. But how to read the file row by row?</s>
2. What is best importing format for constructing a list of graphs, number, string or something else?
3. Are there other ways to construct the list of graph efficiently from a list given above?

**Update:**
Following are the running times for a file with 531441 rows.

```
AbsoluteTiming[mylist=Import["infile.txt","Table"];]
{20.3156, Null}
```

And the method suggested by @RunnyKine gives

```
AbsoluteTiming[mylist=ReadList["infile.txt", Number, RecordLists -> True];]
{4.45186, Null}
```

That's really a big improvement.
The input file (around 35MB) is available from this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qn5w4vrr7f5bfj0/infile.txt?dl=1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should be fast enough:

```
myList = ReadList["infile.txt", Number, RecordLists -> True]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {4.64517, Null}

Comment: I tested your solution on a 35MB file. It turns out it is not as fast as expected. Is it a problem of Mathematica itself?  I'm using Mathematica 10.3.

Comment: @HanXiao. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now it is almost 5 times faster than mine.

Comment: Just a side note: `ReadList` also uses less memory during the import. `Import` causes a memory usage peak of almost 2GB, while `ReadList` isn't really noticeable on the memory side

Comment: @jens_bo. Yes it does use less memory. It's a low level function that's why I prefer using it. It's almost always (if used right) much faster than `Import`